# How to count number of non duplicate value between two sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, countif

I have an excel file with two sheets (sheet1 and sheet2) there are several digit in B10:b100 of these two sheet, some of them are duplicate but i want to count the values which are unique between two sheets , it means that if a value of sheet 2 is exist in sheet 1, it must be ignored.

I tried with below formula bust without successful

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(Sheet1:Sheet2!$B$10:$B$100, Sheet1:Sheet2!$B$10:$B$100)=1))
```

i tried with Sumproduct but with no successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this formula in cell `C10` of `Sheet1`

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B10:$B100,B10),"Duplicate","Not Duplicate")
```

and drag it down.